# SQLAlchemy - Bind params and compile an INSERT statement from TextClause

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to generate the raw SQL required for an insert statement using a DataFrame of values. I am aware of `df.to_sql()`, but I need the actual text query.

I'm not sure how to bind the values to the insert statement itself (when only using the simply `TextClause` instance).

For example,

```py
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sql

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"foo": [1, 2, 3], "bar": ["a", "b", "c"]})

query = sql.text(
    """
    INSERT INTO some_table(Foo, Bar)
    VALUES(:foo, :bar)
    """
)

conn = sql.engine.create_engine("mysql+pymysql://user:pass@localhost:1234/some_db")

# Psuedo code of what I'd like to do
query_with_values = query.bind(df.to_dict(orient="records"))
print(query_with_values.compile(conn))

# And what I'd like to see
# INSERT INTO some_table(Foo, Bar) VALUES (1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")
```

Bonus points if you know how I can specify the type of the columns (as I can if I were using `bindparam`)

Thanks!

Comment: Define an ORM model, and use bulk insert: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/dml.html#orm-bulk-insert-statements